# using sql server temp table while selecting rows from multiple table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several stored procedures (SP) that selects data from multiple tables. Each of this SP has several search parameters that I try to find in different columns of different tables. Instead of making joins on all the tables I am using temp tables to filter out rows from 1 or 2 table joins at a time and storing result in new table and dropping previous ones. The query runs quite faster than writing a single select statement and multiple joins, however I just want to know does it have any site effects to use temp tables and dropping them in select query.
Is there any article which explains with example about any other alternatives on how to write such complicated query for SQL Server 2008?
Please do share about how to keep SQL server using memory efficiently while writing such complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

Although this article is detailing the pros and cons of temporary tables as an alternative to table variables (rather than in a general sense), there are still some good points about why you might want to consider using/not using temporary tables.

[Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84397/table-variables-v-temporary-tables-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Also just got this article through the SQLServerCentral newsletter.  Looks like it may be of use if you're still undecided: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Temporary+Tables/66720/